# Responsive squared images with overlapping one in the middle

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

I'm trying to create a specific layout in which:

- Two images have to be one to the side of the other, filling all the width
- Images height must adapt to create a squared image
- In the middle of both images, an icon or text will be placed, as linking the images
- The external container doesn't have a fixed height nor width

This is a representation of what I'm looking for:

**Side to side images with one overlapping in the center**

[image: Side to side images with one overlapping in the center]

This is what I've managed to do, but it has the *following problems*:

- Depending on the size of the images, the squares take a different size
- The middle icon doesn't go to the middle...

```css
.main_container_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color:lime;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display:flex
}

.image_cell {
    width:50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}
.image_cell img {
     flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
}

.text-cell {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  background:white;
}

.inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container_1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="image_cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x200">
    </div>
    <div class="image_cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
     <div class="text-cell">
       <div class="inner">
         text
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to make your `.row`'s height to be half its width (that would give you space for two squares). To do that you need to use the [padding trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width).

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
```

and then you'll need to position your images absolutely since you're faking their parent's height with padding.

```
.image_cell {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.image_cell:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}

.image_cell:nth-child(2) {
  right: 0;
}
```

and finally you can position your `.text-cell` in the center using `transform` like this (you must make sure to put `position: relative` to the parent container you want to position it relative to, which is `.row` in this case):

```
.text-cell {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here's the final result:

```css
.main_container_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.image_cell {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.image_cell:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}

.image_cell:nth-child(2) {
  right: 0;
}

.image_cell img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.text-cell {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container_1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="image_cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x200">
    </div>
    <div class="image_cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
    <div class="text-cell">
      <div class="inner">
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**One more thing:** you probably want to look into using [background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559817/how-to-keep-aspect-ratio-of-a-background-image) instead to maintain aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I've added a `.square` class to maintain the aspect ratio. The other thing I did is use `justify-content` and `align-items` on the div surrounding the cells in order to center the text cell.

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container .cells {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .cells .image {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    rgb(252, 223, 138) 0%,
    rgb(243, 131, 129) 100%
  );
}

.container .cells .image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .cells .text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #5e2563;
  text-align: center;
}

.container p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
}

.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.square .content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cells">
    <div class="image square">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image square">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      middle
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>This is a variable width and height container</p>
</div>
```